# Joined tables - how to aggregate problem (sum)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, aggregation

I have two tables joined like this:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT T1.ContractNumber) AS nr_of_contracts,
       count(T3.DateofInstallmentPayment) AS nr_of_paid_installents, 
       count(T3.DateofDueInstallment) AS nr_of_installments, 
       sum(T1.DisbursementAmount) AS disbursed_amount

FROM q.T1
LEFT JOIN q.T3
ON T1.ContractNumber=T3.ContractNumber

WHERE   DateOfDisbursement BETWEEN '2019-12-01' AND '2019-12-31'
        AND T3.DateofDueInstallment < GETDATE()
```

where T1 table contains data about clients (per contract number) and T3 about their payment schedules (per every instalment).

What I want is to have paid off amount (disbursement amount) of contracts from table T1 (aggregated by contract number) and not by every instalment. When I tried to select just sum(T1.Disbursement amount) then I receive sum but for all instalment which is incorrect.

T1:

| Contract Number | DisbursementDate | Disbursement Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-12-01 | 1000 |
| 2 | 2019-12-01 | 2000 |
| 3 | 2019-12-01 | 3000 |

T3:

| Contract Number | DateofDueInstallment | DateofInstallmentPayment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-02-06 |
| 1 | 2020-03-01 | 2020-04-01 |

What I get after joining two tables for Contract Number = 1 is sum(DisbursementAmount) = 3000.

| Contract Number | sum(DisbursementAmount) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3000 |

What I want after joining two tables for Contract Number = 1 is sum(DisbursementAmount) = 1000.

| Contract Number | sum(DisbursementAmount) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |

Comment: Please post tables schema, sample data and desired result, preferably using online tool like https://dbfiddle.uk

Comment: T1: ContractNumber, Product, Nr of Installment, DisbursementAmount
T3: ContractNumber, Number_of_installment, Installment_amount_due, Installment_amount_payed

I would like to see aggregated sum of Installments_amount_payed in joined structure (T1 and T3) in every row presenting the same amount (sum of all installments grouped by contract number and not by nr of installment).

Comment: I edited question and simplified it.

Comment: Sample date + expected results i.e. a [mre] would really help.

Comment: Ok, I hope that problem now is visible. Is that OK ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this,not tested - a subquery with a different aggregation column

```
SELECT T1.product, T1.NrOfInstallment, count(DISTINCT T1.ContractNumber), 
           SELECT paid_amound FROM(SELECT ContractNumber, sum(tt.DisbursementAmount + (tt.ContractNumber*0.01))  
                    - sum(tt.ContractNumber*0.01) as paid_amount
    FROM abc.T1 as tt  WHERE tt.ContractNumber = T1.ContractNumber GROUP BY ContractNumber) AS t)                           
    FROM abc.T1
    LEFT JOIN bde.T3
    ON T1.ContractNumber=T3.ContractNumber
    GROUP BY T1.product, T1.NrOfInstallment
```

Comment: I changed a little my select to simplify the problem. Can you now help ?